# dropdown populated with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hello and thank you for your time in advance.

I am looking to populate a dropdown menu from a mysql database using a prepared statement in PHP. I am just looking for any entries that have a matching "client_id". I have seen this addressed many ways (some of them out dated, some of them crazy complicated) but have not been able to find an example that is using php in a way similar enough to what I have been using (see below) so that I can cobble together something that works.

Here is the code I would like to work with.

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');

if ($_POST) {

    if (!empty($_POST['client_id'])) {
        $client_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['client_id']);

        $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT project_id, nickname FROM project WHERE client_id=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $client_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo ("<option value='$row['project_id']'>$row['nickname']</option>");
        }

        $stmt->close();

    }
}

include ('disconnect.php');
?>
```

I know that the echo part is not correct, but I wanted to be able to show what I was thinking at the very least. In general I am not 100% I am using the row variable correctly either. I appreciate any assistance here.

EDIT:

the above file is called "fetchProjects.php"

Here is the code where this PHP file included.

```
<div class="twelve columns">
    <p>select an existing project below</p>     
    <select size="10" name="selectedProject">
        <?php include('fetchProjects.php')?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: I don't see `<select></select>`, nor a matching named element matching `$_POST['client_id']` in a form and `name="client_id"` type of thing.

Comment: I was including this PHP within the <select></select> tags in another file.

Comment: ...in another file; I see.. .well then again I don't ;-) You do.

Comment: btw; you used `fetch()` twice and that alone should be throwing an error.

Comment: the client_id is being provided from a previous page with a form on it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- , i added the code above where this PHP is included. sorry.

Comment: did you check the answers below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Would advise:

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['client_id'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['client_id'])) {
        $client_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['client_id']);

        $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT project_id, nickname FROM project WHERE client_id=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $client_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($pid, $nick);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo ("<option value='$pid'>$nick</option>");
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
}

include ('disconnect.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bind_result, on each iteration of the while loop $project_id and $nickname get updated with the current database row values

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT project_id, nickname FROM project WHERE client_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $client_id);
$stmt->bind_result($project_id, $nickname);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$project_id.'">'.$nickname.'</option>';
}

$stmt->close();
```

*Not tested but it should work*

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to assign your fetch here:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {...
```

It should be:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {...
```

Now the array elements you try to access with `$row` will work. You should delete your first fetch, because that will consume the first row of data. One more thing: you do not need parentheses areound your `echo`.